# Meaning of Korean phrases structure suffixes

Tags: particle, phrases, suffix, sentence-endings

Do korean structure suffixes have any meaning alone or they only have meaning when used with verbs, adjectives, etc?

For example V+곤 하다. Does "곤 하다" have any meaning alone as an expression? I know "하다" has meaning alone, as a verb, but I've never seen "곤" alone.

I could also make this question for every structure suffix that there is: do they have meaning alone or they are more like particles: meaningless alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"곤 하다" doesn't have any meaning alone as an expression.

For example, at least it must be used with "하". ("하곤 한다" / "하고는 한다")

"곤" stands for "고는". and it doesn't have meaning alone.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Are there any of these suffixes that have meaning alone? Or maybe you have any surce I can check to know more about this and the ethimology of these suffixes? I am curious about this because Korean is the first language I am aware of that has this type of meaningless words used for grammarly purpouses.

Comment: Suffixes don't have meaning alone. It should be used with a verb. `하고는 한다(~고는 한다), 빠르기는 하다(~기는 하다). 그렇기는 하다(기는 하다)`. Have you seen the sentence that uses only suffixes?

Comment: Not really, I was just curious about it.

Comment: Goood. I hope your confusion be reduced.

Comment: But is it true for every suffix that exists in Korean?

Comment: I don't remember using that more than 30 years in Korea. If that really exists, it would be a very unusual or exceptional case.(for example, a newly coined word) If you find it, please write a comment. I'll check it out.